# Graphing multiple csv lists into one graph in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, graph

I have 5 csv files that I am trying to put into one graph in python. In the first column of each csv file, all of the numbers are the same, and I want to treat these as the x values for each csv file in the graph. However, there are two more columns in each csv file (to make 3 columns total), but I just want to graph the second column as the 'y-values' for each csv file on the same graph, and ideally get 5 different lines, one for each file. Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

I have already uploaded my files to the variable file_list

Comment: Does any of the answer below solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your files are named `File0.csv`, `File1.csv`, `File2.csv`, `File3.csv`, `File4.csv`, you can loop over them, ignore the third column values and plot the x and y values. The following pseudo code will work **for 3 columns**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(5):
    x, y, _ = np.loadtxt('File%s.csv' %i, unpack=True)
    plt.plot(x, y, label='File %s' %i)
plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the first file and create a list of lists in which each list filled by two columns of this file. Then read the other files one by one and append y column of them to the correspond index of this list.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call plot more than once. Assuming you `from matplotlib.pyplot import plot`, You can repeat the same x values, or have different ones and it will still work. Here is an example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

files = list(Path("/path/to/folder/with/csvs").glob("*.csv"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
x_col, y_col = "x_column_name", "y_column_name"

for file in files:
    file_name = file.stem
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df.plot(x=x_col, y=y_col, ax=ax, label=file_name, legend=True)

fig  # If using a jupyter notebook, and you've run a cell with %matplotlib inline
```